# Ext - javascript null exception on init - hiddenField

Tags: extjs

My Ext (Sencha) page throws this JS error when it initialises:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null - ext-all-debug.js:89797
```

it errors on this line:

```
 startUp: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.currentToken = me.hiddenField.value
```

Because 'hiddenField' is null.
Without pasting the entire page content (it's very big, and under NDA), can anyone tell what I should look for that might be on my page that's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you're using the History and haven't created the appropriate hidden/iframe elements that it needs. Have a look at the history example for the version you're using.

Comment: You could easily verify it by looking at the code around the exception, it's the History code, it's looking for a hidden field.